# How do I explicitly make sure my restore, build and publish settings are consistent in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I run the following command:

```
 "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" new console
```

I get the following errors:

```
C:\Temp\myapp\myapp\myapp.csproj : warning NU1603: myapp depends on 
Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.1.0) but Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 was not found. 
An approximate best match of Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 was resolved.

C:\Temp\myapp\myapp\myapp.csproj : error : The project was restored using 
Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.1, but with current settings, version 2.1.0 
would be used instead.  To resolve this issue, make sure the same settings 
are used for restore and for subsequent operations such as build or publish.  
Typically this issue can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set 
during build or publish but not during restore.
```

When I run dotnet --info I get the following:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.301
 Commit:    59524873d6

 Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.301\

Host (useful for support):
Version: 2.1.1
Commit:  6985b9f684

.NET Core SDKs installed:
 2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
 2.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

 .NET Core runtimes installed:
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 [C:\Program 
 Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program 
 Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
 Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program 
 Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
 Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program 
 Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

 To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
 https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

And finally in the myapp.csproj file that is generated:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I have searched the internet and it seems many people have the same issue.  I'm curious as to what is happening and how to fix it.  I'm guessing I can be more explicit in my CLI commands but I'm not sure how and what to be explicit about.

To complicate things further, I thought I could install Visual Studio 2017 and see how it builds a Dotnet Core console application.  I figured it would install all of the dependencies necessary and build the files for the project in a way that would just work.

I was surprised to see the csproj file use 1.1 as the target framework:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I experienced many build errors including the following:

```
    Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App with version (>= 1.1.2)
    - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ 
    Nearest version: 1.0.0-rc2-3002702 ]
    - Found 0 version(s) in MyDownloads ConsoleApp1  
    C:\Users\admin\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj  1
```

UPDATE

I reinstalled both .NET Core SDK 2.1 x86 and x64.  I create a new .NET Console App in Visual Studio 2017.  It would not build.  I received the following error:

```
Assets file not found project.assets.json.  Run a nuget restore to create file.
```

A nuget restore runs with no errors but creates no such file.

I built the same project from  the command line and the project.assets.json was created and the project builds and runs.  My Visual Studio instance has the latest updates.  What is broke or missing in my instance of Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?

Comment: Yes.  I can not make it build via the command line after reinstalling the SDKs but I don't understand why I am having the issue from "UPDATE" down in Visual Studio.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I ran into these issues the other day. I solved this simply by matching my Build configuration and CPU architecture with the one I was publishing with.

Microsoft goes over the issues with this in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-patch-selection) as well

They specify that you build using the expected configuration first and then publish using the `no-restore` option

```
dotnet publish --no-restore -r win10-x64
```

**edit**
I think you need to update your csproj file

```
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1.1</TargetFramework>
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
 <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

If that doesn't work there are a few solutions which you can try.
you can create a `global.json` to specify which SDK Version:

```
{
    "sdk": { "version": "2.1.300" }
}
```

If that doesn't work there are a few other solution which may help, you can find them in
this issue open for it on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3221).

Comment: Hi @johnny5.  I tried your latest advice and I am still having the issue.  I guess I'll continue to manually build.  I'm guessing there will be an update for Visual Studio soon enough to fix some of these issues.  Dotnetcore is moving so fast I know it's hard for the team to keep up.  They're doing a great job considering how much everything has changed in the Microsoft ecosystem in the past two years.